# Convergence in distribution sequence of exponential random variable

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables, weak-convergence

Given X- Exp(1) an exponential random variable with rate parameter λ = 1 and let (Y) be the sequence of independent real random variables such that

$$Y_n = \begin{cases} n & \text{if}\ 0\leq \ X < \frac{1}{n},\\ 0 & \text{if}\ \frac{1}{n}\leq X\end{cases} \quad \forall n \geq 1$$

**Question:**
Does (Y) converges in distribution?

I need to demonstrate the convergence explicitly so I tried to find the distribution function. Here's what I attempted to do:

$$ P(Y_n=n) = P(X  \in [0, \frac{1}{n}]) = P(0 \leq X \leq \frac{1}{n}) = 1 - e^\frac{-1}{n}$$
$$P(Y_n = 0) = P(X\in[\frac{1}{n}, \infty])= P(\frac{1}{n}\leq X) = 1- P(X\leq\frac{1}{n}) = e^\frac{-1}{n}$$

So I thought that Yn is a Bernoulli with states 0 and n and success probability exp(-1/n) and my distribution function is something like that:

$$F_Y(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if}\ 0 < \ x ,\\ 1 - e^\frac{-1}{n} & \text{if}\ 0\leq x < n \\ 1 &\text{if}\ x \geq n\end{cases} $$

But I am not sure about this, can anyone please help me? My main problem is how to find the distribution function of a sequence. Thank you

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\omega$ note that $Y_n(\omega)=0$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Hence $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely and this implies convergence in distribution also.

Alternatively we have:

Let $x >0$. $P(Y_n \leq x)=P(\frac  1 n \leq X)=e^{-\frac  1 n}$ for all $n >x$. So the lim it of $P(Y_n \leq x)$ is $1$.  It is clear that $P(Y_n \leq x) \to 0$ for $x <0$. Hence the limiting distribution function $F$ is such that $F(x)=1$ for $x >0$ and $0$ for $x <1$. This means that  $Y_n \to 0$ in distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I need to demonstrate the convergence in distribution explicitly by finding the distribution function

Comment: @LeonardoPetraglia I have added another argument.